# Navigate to route using hashHistory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I've setup my routes in my react application like so:

```
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

// Pages
import Layout from './pages/Layout/Layout';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import CityOverview from './pages/CityOverview/CityOverview';
import GameOne from './pages/GameOne/GameOne';
import PageTwo from './pages/PageTwo/PageTwo';
import PageThree from './pages/PageThree/PageThree';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path='/city-overview' component={CityOverview}></Route>
            <Route path='/game-one' component={GameOne}></Route>
            <Route path='/page-two' component={PageTwo}></Route>
            <Route path='/page-three' component={PageThree}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But I'm struggling to navigate from one page to another, for example:

// Home.js
hashHistory.push('/city-overview);

The URL changes in the browser but it doesn't actually navigate to that route...

Comment: `hashHistory` should be fine to use. There is no error being thrown? What is the `nextState` value in this callback function? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/createTransitionManager.js#L217 That should include the route components for the new location.

Answer (score 1):

I use `contextType` in my component for react-router.

```
static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

and to change the route inside the component based on some action -

```
this.context.router.replace({
    pathname : '/'/city-overview',
    state    : {
        // some state data if you need to pass
        // key : val
    }
});
```

Comment: when I do this i get the following error: app.js:50850 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined(…)

Comment: Which version of react-router u use? Have you used contextTypes in your component?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with **react-router 2** you should not use the `history` object to do the navigation, you should use the router instead.

```
static contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

and then navigate like

```
this.context.router.push(/city-overview');
```

You should use it like

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () =>{
        this.context.router.push('/city-overview');
    }
    static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    }
    render() {
        return (    
            <div className="flex-container-center">
              <button type="button" onClick={this.props.handleClick}>submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If your are using react-router version < v2.0 then you should use the history  object like

```
 static contextTypes: {
    history: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
 }
```

and then use it like

```
this.context.history.push('/city-overview');
```

This works for both `hashHistory` and `browserHistory`

Comment: when i do this I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)